# Which tool should we use to execute stored procedures against PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.2

I have some stored procedures that return ref cursors. The manual suggests a somewhat convoluted approach to execute them and view the results:

```
-- need to be in a transaction to use cursors.
BEGIN;
SELECT reffunc2();

      reffunc2
--------------------
 <unnamed cursor 1>
(1 row)

FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed cursor 1>";
COMMIT;
```

When I tried that, my SQL Manager Lite hung on me. I had no problem consuming the result set from my client developed in C#.

Is there a simple tool my users and I should use to execute stored procs that return ref cursors?

Comment: Default psql client works fine with cursors.

Comment: This looks like a problem with `SQL Manager Lite`, not so much with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

In general, my experience is that the command-line psql client is the single best general tool you will ever find for PostgreSQL.  It is intended for scripting and can generate all kinds of different output formats, but it also works fine interactively.  Refcursors can be a bit odd, as many of the GUI tools do not handle them very well (as there is no interaction within a transaction).  IIRC, this is an issue with pgadmin too.

Otherwise, if you have something more special-purpose, your best bet is to build a tool for that purpose only.